# How can I upload a image using CKEditor on rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, rails-admin

Is there any way to do that?

I found CKFinder but it seems it doesnt work on rails.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding the following to my rails_admin.rd in config/initailizers

```
   config.model Page do
  #   # Found associations:

  #   # Found columns:
  #     field :id, :integer 
       field :title, :string 
       field :menu, :string 
  #     field :parent_id, :integer 
       field :live, :boolean
       field :orderby, :integer 
       field :content, :text do
        ckeditor true
      end 
  #     field :created_at, :datetime 
  #     field :updated_at, :datetime 
  #   # Sections:
     list do; end
     export do; end
     show do; end
     edit do; end
     create do; end
     update do; end
   end
```